# How to access C/C++ arrays in Python via pybind11

Tags: python, c++, arrays, pointers, pybind11

I'm trying to make some C/C++ codes available in Python via pybind11, and in the C/C++ codes, a pointer to an array is returned, and I'd like to access the array in Python either as a list or a NumPy array.

I tested the following implementation:

```
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>

int* get_zeros(int n) {
    int* a = new int[n];
    memset(a, 0, n);
    return a;
}

PYBIND11_MODULE(example, m) {
    m.def("get_zeros", &get_zeros);
}
```

But when I called `get_zeros` in Python, it only returned an address (like `-1375731712`), so how can I access the array in Python using pybind11?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to return a type that pybind11 interprets as an array. A pointer will not work, because pybind11 does not know the size of the array.

If you return `std::vector` or in case of fixed dimension `std::array` this will be converted to a list.

The drawback is that the data is copied, so modifications in python are not visible in c++.

Alternatively you can create a numpy array (`pybind11::array_t`) directly and return that instead. Then no data is copied and changes in Python will be visible in C++ and vice versa.

You can also create a numpy array from an existing data buffer in pybind11, just as in Python. However then you need to do lifetime management yourself.

You could also create a custom class in pybind11 that implements the array access members used by Python. In that way you can connect every C++ object to python.

I would suggest you to work with numpy arrays. If you stick to a certain memory layout (e.g. C or Fortran order) with contiguous storage, you can get the pointer to the data from the numpy array and work with that pointer your C++ routines.

Comment: Thanks, std::vector works, but `pybind11/stl.h` needs be included.

Comment: yes, unfortunately not all functionality is included in `pybind11.h`. I guess you would need also to include `numpy.h` for `array_t` to work.